# How to tune the hyperparameters of a Bayesian ODE fit in Julia?

Tags: julia, ode, ijulia-notebook, julia-gpu

I have been trying to replicate https://diffeqflux.sciml.ai/dev/examples/BayesianNODE_NUTS/, using different ODE equation, but I have received this result without uncertainty quantification, is it because I did the initial value u0 is higher :

[image]

Could you please tell me what was wrong?

```
   using DiffEqFlux, OrdinaryDiffEq, Flux, Optim, Plots, AdvancedHMC, MCMCChains
using JLD, StatsPlots

function Arps!(du,u,p,t)
    y= u[1]
    #x, y = u
   # Di,b,n,tau = p
    n,tau = p
    #du[1]=dx=-(x * Di * x^b)
    du[1]=dy=-(n *((t^n)/tau) * y/t)
end
tspan=(1.0,50.0)
tsteps = 1:1:50
u0 = [16382.9]
p=[0.48,15.92]
prob_trueode = ODEProblem(Arps!,u0,tspan,p)
ode_data = Array(solve(prob_trueode, Tsit5(), saveat = tsteps))
ode_data =ode_data[1,:]

dudt= FastChain(FastDense(1, 30, tanh),
                  FastDense(30, 1))

prob_neuralode = NeuralODE(dudt, tspan, Tsit5(), saveat = tsteps)

function predict_neuralode(p)
    Array(prob_neuralode(u0, p))
end

function loss_neuralode(p)
    pred = predict_neuralode(p)
    loss = sum(abs2, ode_data .- pred)
    return loss, pred
end

l(θ) = -sum(abs2, ode_data .- predict_neuralode(θ)) - sum(θ .* θ)


function dldθ(θ)
    x,lambda = Flux.Zygote.pullback(l,θ)
    grad = first(lambda(1))
    return x, grad
end

metric  = DiagEuclideanMetric(length(prob_neuralode.p))

h = Hamiltonian(metric, l, dldθ)


integrator = Leapfrog(find_good_stepsize(h, Float64.(prob_neuralode.p)))


prop = AdvancedHMC.NUTS{MultinomialTS, GeneralisedNoUTurn}(integrator)

adaptor = StanHMCAdaptor(MassMatrixAdaptor(metric), StepSizeAdaptor(0.45, prop.integrator))

samples, stats = sample(h, prop, Float64.(prob_neuralode.p), 500, adaptor, 500; progress=true)
losses = map(x-> x[1],[loss_neuralode(samples[i]) for i in 1:length(samples)])

################### RETRODICTED PLOTS: TIME SERIES #################
pl = scatter(tsteps, ode_data, color = :red, label = "Data: Var1", xlabel = "t", title = "Spiral Neural ODE")
for k in 1:300
    resol = predict_neuralode(samples[100:end][rand(1:400)])
    plot!(tsteps,resol[1,:], alpha=0.04, color = :red, label = "")
end

idx = findmin(losses)[2]
prediction = predict_neuralode(samples[idx])
plot!(tsteps,prediction[1,:], color = :black, w = 2, label = "")
```

Comment: Are you on v1.5 with the latest version?

Comment: @ChrisRackauckas  I am using Version 1.5.3

Comment: for free form discussion you should use a forum like discourse.julialang.org or julialang.org/slack. StackOverflow is generally used for programming Q&A. Tuning a fitting process to a specific example is generally more of a back-and-forth process not quite fitting to the Q&A style.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most likely reason for this is because the loss function magnitude is too high for the posterior samples, due to which the posterior sample results are out of range and not visible on your plot.

This can be possibly fixed by (a) adding a scaling factor the Neural ODE output and making sure that the loss function does not start from a very high magnitude or (b) increasing the number of layers in the neural network architecture/ changing the activation function.

Comment: This is a good answer. Indeed it seems the code isn't incorrect, but the user had changed the differential equation, initial condition, and parameters without changing the hyperparameters of the fitting process. Generally for Bayesian estimation you will need to tune the training process a bit, so the question of what to try is a very open ended computational science question and not a well-defined programming question. Such open ended questions probably should be asked at https://discourse.julialang.org/ instead.

Answer (score 2):

By adding scaling factor to the Neural ODE, I have got good results as shown in the figure below:

[image]